# Did grep change how it uses regexp?

Tags: grep, regex

I used to run commands like: find /dev | grep sd* to output a list of all the drives attached to my computer. It appears that I now have to add **any random character** before the star in order to get the same affect as shown below:

[image: sudo find /dev | grep sdp*]

I tested this on various Ubuntu 12.04 servers and got the same effect, so I do not think this is just something random on my desktop. Is this a new change, a bug, or has it always been this way and my memory needs replacing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two problems:

- [Globbing](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html) interferes with your regexp
- Your regexp doesn't match what is should match

## Uncovering the globbing mechanism

`sudo find /dev | grep sd*` doesn't work as before because you have a file or a folder in your current working directory which triggers the globbing from bash. Add a `echo` in front of your command to see what globbing does to your command

```
echo grep sd*
```

By adding a random additional character, globbing didn't match the file/folder anymore and grep continued to work as expected.

## How to prevent globbing

To prevent globbing from kicking in, you have to put `'...'` around your term.  (Double quotes will work also.) This will make grep behave as before:

```
sudo find /dev | grep 'sd*'
```

## How regular expressions work

Now that the [regexp](http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/) is working as expected let's look at what `*` means in regular expressions as opposed to file globbing.  In short it means "This last character zero or n-times" and this is most probably not what you want.  Using `'sd*'` you might see `/dev/stdout` in the output, since `stdout` starts with an `s` followed by **zero** or more `d`'s.

In your case a simple:

```
sudo find /dev | grep sd
```

should be all you need to match.

---

Or, of course, you could just run one of the following commands (which use file glob patterns, not regular expressions) to give you the same output:

```
find /dev -name 'sd*'
ls -1 /dev/sd*
```

Comment: `find /dev | grep "sd*"` resulted in the same effect, whilst `echo find /dev | grep sd*` output nothing: http://img811.imageshack.us/img811/2451/g7a.png

Comment: Added more sudoness and suggested another solution.

Comment: nvm, Im pretty sure im getting two commands I use mixed up: `ls /dev/sd*` and `find /dev | grep sd` Either of these work as I was expecting.

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 
“I know, I'll use regular expressions.”   Now they have two problems. -- [Quote](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247)